# Extract all git tag with the pattern digit.digit.digit

Tags: git, filter, tags, glob

I have a list of git tags:

```
0.0.1
0.0.1-rc.0
0.0.1-rc.1
0.1.0
0.10.0
0.10.1-rc.0
0.11.0
0.11.1-rc.0
0.12.0
0.12.1-rc.0
0.13.0
0.13.1-hotfix.0
0.13.1-rc.0
0.14.0
0.14.1-rc.0
0.15.0
0.15.1-rc.0
0.16.0
0.16.1-rc.0
0.17.0
0.17.1-rc.0
0.18.0
0.18.1-hotfix.0
```

I'm aiming to extract the all tags haveing this pattern : digit.digit.digit. this tags are :

```
0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.10.0 , 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.10.0
```

I've tried these expressions, and none of them gave me the result I need :

```
git tag --list "[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]" :
   0.0.1
   0.1.0

git tag --list "[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+" : no result
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git tag --list` accepts [wildcard (glob) patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not regular expressions. So try

```
git tag -l '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*'
```

To filter with regular expression use an external tools like `grep`:

```
git tag --list | grep -E "^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$"
```

Comment: git tag -l '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*' doesnt work, it gave me all the tags

Comment: I will try the second one, because I'm oworking with this code : https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/blob/master/assets/check#L158

Comment: Alas, glob patterns are rather weak. Use `grep`.

Comment: I improved the regexp: added `^$` anchors.

Comment: it works! thank you very much! 

    tag_regex: "[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+"